# How to modify material UI datagrid checkbox icon?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Here is the codesandbox. I want to use my customized checkbox in the Datagrid. So I would like to change the first column checkbox to a round checkbox. I already have the wrapper round checkbox I want to use, but I do not know how to replace the default checkbox in datagrid. It looks like I should use slots Checkbox, but did not write it correctly,

https://codesandbox.io/s/datatable-material-demo-with-different-checkbox-mo715?file=/demo.js
[image]

Answer (score 6):

You need to use the [slots](https://mui.com/components/data-grid/components/#overriding-components) api to override components in the [Material UI DataGrid](https://mui.com/api/data-grid/data-grid/) library.

You should include the code in your question so others can benefit. You have this:

```js
export default function DataTable() {
  return (
    <div style={{ height: 400, width: "100%" }}>
      <Checkbox />
      <DataGrid
        rows={rows}
        columns={columns}
        pageSize={5}
        rowsPerPageOptions={[5]}
        checkboxSelection
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Which just renders a round `<Checkbox/>` from your library above the `<DataGrid/>`. If you instead pass the `<Checkbox/>` to the `component` prop it will use that instead.

```js
export default function DataTable() {
  return (
    <div style={{ height: 400, width: "100%" }}>
      <DataGrid
        components={{
          Checkbox: Checkbox,
        }}
        rows={rows}
        columns={columns}
        pageSize={5}
        rowsPerPageOptions={[5]}
        checkboxSelection
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 5):

if you're still wondering about this, or anybody else who wants to do this, I checked your example code and made a fork here with the solution:

https://codesandbox.io/s/datatable-material-demo-with-different-checkbox-forked-n1cnz0?file=/demo.js

Basically, the component should be passed in to `BaseCheckbox` and the custom checkbox needs to pass the props through.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JiZoV.png)

Comment: Thank you for the sandbox example.  For others that happen-upon this post, the `Checkbox` slot that worked in v4 seems to have been renamed to `BaseCheckbox` in v5 (as you have it).  Swapping out the name fixed my grid "just like that" :)

Answer (score 0):

For those on version 5, here's what I used to modify the icons.

I am using FontAwesome, but you could replace the icon with anything else that may work inside IconButton.

```
const checkedIcon = (
  <IconButton>
    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSquareCheck} />
  </IconButton>
)

const unCheckedIcon = (
  <IconButton>
    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSquare} />
  </IconButton>
)


return (
   <DataGrid
      rows={rows}
      columns={columns}
      pageSize={5}
      rowsPerPageOptions={[5]}
      checkboxSelection
      components={{
        BaseCheckbox: (props) => (
          <Checkbox {...props} checkedIcon={checkedIcon} icon={unCheckedIcon} />
        ),
      }}
    />
)
```

Tested on MUI v5.17.12.